# iPhone Scaling: Can't see full website

Tags: iphone, html, css, media-queries

I'm having some issues with a page that doesn't have a lot of content and therefore has a small height. The iPhone is scaling the page, and due to this, I can't see the full menu bar (960px wide). I put a minimum height using a media query for both portrait mode and mobile devices with a minimum resolution. I really dislike doing this as I don't know how this will work on other devices, and it only works if the user doesn't rotate the screen (after rotation, the original issue re-occurs).

Is there some way to force the iphone to show a minimum width of 960px even if the height of the content doesn't fill the screen?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code?  That would be helpful.

Comment: Try using the meta tag for viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can control the viewport width, and maximum scale (depth visitor is allowed to zoom in) for Apple mobile devices with this META tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=960px, maximum-scale=1.0" />`

Works with Android and other mobile browsing devices, too.

Comment: This is definitely better, but you still have to scroll to the right to see the full menu bar. I still can't get it to show all 960 pixels without scrolling.

Comment: Did you try setting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=960px, minimum-scale=#.#" />` to play with the minimum scale?

Comment: If that's the case, something in your HTML or CSS may be extending beyond the 960 px. You can try a larger viewport, or examine your code to see if there is an element or property affecting the menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

By default iOS browsers supply a set of default screen dimensions, regardless of actual screen res *or orientation*.

In order to get them to supply @media tags with **the actual screen dimensions** there is a Meta tag they will obey:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you add this to your page(s) then your @media commands should work with the *actual screen resolution* of each device. You then have full control with your @media queries

You can then use things like `width: 100%` to use the actual screen width.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag